# Error while parsing json  in J2ME

Tags: json, java-me

I am running Java ME application in Eclipse..I have JSON code in my pp and I have also json.jar lib, but when I run the application, I get an eror like this.

```
Uncaught exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/me/JSONObject
 - parsing.Parsing$1.run(), bci=88
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your json.jar lib is not bundled with your app code. The contents from json.jar must be available inside the final app jar file.

If you are using Eclipse Pulsar be sure to check this lib at Project .. Properties .. Java Build Path .. Order and Export tab.

Comment: Do you still have the jar file? I can't find the json-me jar anythere :S